# When I install the package "summarytools" on R studio and then call the library, I get an error

Tags: r, r-package

```
install.packages("summarytools")
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.3/summarytools_1.0.1.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1414699 bytes (1.3 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.3 MB


The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/4t/lfjy1jsn0c11dxf3l_g9js2h0000gn/T//Rtmp6kkciG/downloaded_packages
> library(summarytools)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘summarytools’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tcltk', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: X11 library is missing: install XQuartz from www.xquartz.org
```

I tried running it again

Comment: Hi Sofia M, welcome to SO. The error message is telling you the issue. In order for `summarytools` to work, ou need to also install `XQuartz`. If the problem persists after installing XQuartz,  update your question to state that you also tried that. Thanks